# Unable to connect to MySQL through port 3306 Windows Server 2012 R2

Tags: mysql, windows-server-2012-r2, port, mysql8

It looks like weird happening, I've followed and fixed all the possible things but still `MySQL` port 3306 is not accessible remotely.

Here's my setup:

**Machine:** Windows Server 2012 R2

**MySQL Server:** 8.xx

**Settings have been applied:**

1. In `my.ini` `bind-address` did to 0.0.0.0 and and thus after exec command `netstat -an` this is what I get `TCP    0.0.0.0:3306           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING`
2. From Windows Firewall I've enabled port `3306` inbound/outbound both.  and set that to `allow edge traversal` as well
3. From the MySQL server I've created a user with `%` all host and then provided permission to all databases as well. which has been checked

I guess these are the actions I took afterward. But this is not working at all.

When I'm trying to do `telnet server_ip 3306` error: `Connecting To server_ip ...Could not open a connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed` from other machines. The local host is working fine.

I don't see any other workaround could else may cause this issue?

Comment: What's result for "telnet 127.0.0.1 3306" locally?